# Android Open GLES 2.0 shadow for 2D object

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, shadow

I did some experiments regarding rendering 2D objects. Now I want to add some shadow or light effect in that 2D object I don't know how to do that. I search and I got some posts regarding this. http://blog.shayanjaved.com/2011/05/20/android-opengl-es-2-0-shadow-mapping/.  But I am not able to understand. So Is there any one who can explain this concept properly ?

Comment: Clarify what kind of shadow effect you are trying to achieve, e.g post a link with a pic? Simple shadow effect for 2D objects ( sprites? ) should be easy by drawing same object first, darkened and blurred? Complex shadow-fu is for 3D objects not 2D...

Comment: Thank you for replay tea.Is it possible to make shadow effect using light source for 2d objects?

Comment: In short, yes! But again, provide an example showing the desired result. If you have a sprite and all your geometry is 2D, your shadow effect (whether linked with a light source or not) would have to be 'faked', for example you can offset said blurred, darkened copy of first object according to direction of light source. Is this what you want to do? It will be easier if you have basic understanding of shaders (or at least you know how to use sample shader code)

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to do shadows and most are too complex to be practical on Android. Most of the shadows you see in games use much simpler and faster approaches, such as texturing. You should get the free PowerVR OpenGL ES 1.1 SDK.  It has an excellent demo named ShadowTechniques which implements and compares several of the best ways to do shadows and it is portable to Android and OpenGL ES 2.0.

```
http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/sdk_licence_agreement.asp
```

Comment: Thank you repay ClayMontgomery. I'll go through this. I am not game developer. I Just want to render few tings or few objects in opengl. Those objects are 2d objects.so how to do that using simple android open gles 2.0 and without any external lib. thank you help.